# How to run Geoserver on a specific IP except Localhost?

Tags: ip, geoserver

I have installed Geoserver . It is running at localhost 8080. I want to run it on a specific IP. How it is possible?

I have created one instance at AWS using windows platform and OS is windows server 2016. I have installed Geoserver into this instance. Geoserver is running on localhost 8080. I want to run Geoserver on this instance IP. How it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

It will already be available at the IP address of your machine. You may need to open port 8080 in the firewall.

If you want to make the getcapabilities files reflect a different external IP of the machine you might need to set the `Proxy Base URL` on the global settings panel.

Comment: I have opened port 8080 in the firewall. but still GeoServer is not running on that IP. What will i do next?